# Spreadsheet App Script > Updating Calendar Events and deleting past entries

Tags: calendar

I am fairly new to app script so sorry for the beginner question...

I have this script (see below) which works well to add calendar events to my team calendar and to invite my colleagues as guests. The issue is that I ran the script and sent the invites but now I have to edit the dates.. When I run the script again it just add the new dates without deleting the wrong previous entries...

Could you try help me modifying this script to ensure it will edit or delete previous entries instead of creating new ones? I have created another column called "event id" in order to capture events id but I don't really know how to make use of it in the script...

Let me know
thanks a lot for your help

```
function CalendarTest() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var index = 2;
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
for (;index <= lastrow; index++){
var title = sheet.getRange(index,1,1,1).getValue();
var startTime = sheet.getRange(index,2,1,1).getValue();
var endTime = sheet.getRange(index,3,1,1).getValue();
var description = sheet.getRange(index,4,1,1).getValue();
var location = sheet.getRange(index,5,1,1).getValue();
var guests = sheet.getRange(index,6,1,1).getValue();
var sendInvites = true;
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById("mycalendarID").createEvent(title,startTime, endTime,
{description: description, location: location, guests: guests, sendInvites });
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Apple Script? Google Apps Script? Something else? Questions about thousands of tools and programming languages are asked and answered here, so please be precise and also tag your question accordingly.